# SQL Server 2012 on Amazon RDS cannot attach mdf with Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

I have set up a Sql Server 2012 on my amazon rds. I have verified i am running the 2012 server and i am able to connect with my username and password that i have created during the wizard creation process from amazon aws. I am trying to attach a mdf and when i right click databases and select attach i can move on to the next menu.. clicking add to select mdf file location results in this error...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kynPZ.png

Running this also

```
USE master
go 
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO myuser;
Go
```

The result is

```
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

I don't understand how i can create the server with the username but not have any admin privileges and not have the ability to escalate them. Is their a way to fix this?

(i have tried running management studio as administrator as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted amazon and the answer was that you cannot attach a mfd because it does not have file system access.

Comment: i wished they would allow(seems if we need to we HAVE to use EC2) and manually setup all backup (no easy-mirroring) *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a new database which was detached by mistake.
Doesn't work:

- dropping it
- importing the DB from a SQL file that was previously exported

In my case, as the attach was not working, I was interested in just using the **same name** for the database and to discard the non-attachable database.
If you are interested in such a solution please read bellow:

- Using SQL Server Management Studio select the databases folder, right-click and choose **New Database** name the new database as the old one and make sure the .mdf files will point to the exact same location as the old one (should be something like D:\RDSDBDATA\DATA\'bd_name'.mdf).
- Then drop the newly created DB: drop database 'db_name'
- Import the database from the sql file